# Implementing a web service - choosing the right (Microsoft based) technology as at February 2014

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Every now and then I need to build a web application. Because this is an occasional need I have the problem of bringing myself up-to-date with current technology whilst at the same time trading off the time required for leaning against the imperative to deliver. Within my current iteration I need to implement 3 web applications that will access some common data via a web service using ajax.

My first prototype for this has been to create an ajax enabled WCF service hosted in IIS, however I have hit a snag in the form of a lack of Cross Origin Resource Sharing support for Chrome and Firefox (strangely IE woks in my prototype.

There is a LOT of information out there on this subject but most of it is 6 months old or older. When I try to map the various examples to my simple start point I am left confused and wondering 2 things.

1. Has this problem already been solved; i.e. Using Visual Studio 2013 can I simply change some configuration that makes cross origin support work or do I really have to implement preflight request handling etc?
2. Am I doing the right thing by starting with WCF or should I look at WebAPI (I am not building an MVC application)

Comment: Here is Microsoft's guidance on the subject.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Darrel. I was hoping for a bit of "experience based opinion". According to this article WCF is more suited to my needs but it does not really tackle the detail issues such as cross domain support. I have some prior experience with WCF, hence this is where I started but I am a bit phased by the need to start implementing code deep in the way that IIS routes messages just to make a simple web service work.

Comment: If your client is a web browser, I'm not sure how the Microsoft guidance could lead you to select WCF.  To my knowledge there are no WCF clients that run in a web browser.  If you are talking about using the WCF REST library then I wouldn't even think about that.  Web API was originally built by the WCF team to replace WCF REST.